# How to do a INNER JOIN on multiple columns of the same table in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, select, inner-join, resultset

I have the following problem: I have three tables: log, media and users.

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
ROW_FORMAT=DEFAULT;
```

```
CREATE TABLE `media` (
  `id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
ROW_FORMAT=DEFAULT;
```

```
CREATE TABLE `log` (
  `id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `action` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `action_time` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `user_id` INTEGER NOT NULL,
  `affected_user_id` INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
  `media_id` INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
  `comment` TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
ROW_FORMAT=DEFAULT;
```

The point with the log table is, that every action that is made, is done by a user, but some actions affect a user, and some actions affect a media, but not always. Some actions affect both a user and a media.
The columns user_id, affected_user_id are foreign keys to users.id
The column media_id is a foreign key to media.id
If there isn't a value for the column, the value is NULL.

What I want to do is to make a SELECT query on log, and INNER JOIN with the other two tables.

First I tried this query, not knowing something was wrong, so this would be my first attempt doing something like this:

```
SELECT log.action, log.action_time, log.user_id, user_name_table.name AS user_name, 
log.affected_user_id, affected_user_name_table.name AS affected_user_name, 
log.media_id, media.title AS media_title, log.comment 
FROM log 
INNER JOIN users AS user_name_table ON user_name_table.id = log.user_id 
INNER JOIN users AS affected_user_name_table ON affected_user_name_table.id = log.affected_user_id 
INNER JOIN media ON media.id = log.media_id 
WHERE log.user_id=1 OR log.affected_user_id=1
```

I looked up on the internet how to INNER JOIN the same table on two columns, I don't really know if it's correct, maybe that's also the problem. I expected this query to return me all the columns of the log table and the names of the users associated with user_id and affected_user_id.

In the log table, there a enough rows which have either user_id=1 or affected_user_id=1. But somehow, my result set is empty. I am not getting an error message, so my query syntax should be ok.

I also tried a few other versions like these:

```
SELECT log.action, log.action_time, log.user_id, users.name AS user_name, log.affected_user_id, 
log.media_id, media.title AS media_title, log.comment 
FROM log 
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = log.user_id OR users.id=log.affected_user_id
INNER JOIN media ON media.id = log.media_id 
WHERE log.user_id=1 OR log.affected_user_id=1
```

```
SELECT log.action, log.action_time, log.user_id, users.name AS user_name, 
log.affected_user_id, 
log.media_id, media.title AS media_title, log.comment 
FROM log 
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = log.user_id = affected_user_id
INNER JOIN media ON media.id = log.media_id 
WHERE log.user_id=1 OR log.affected_user_id=1
```

I've searched the internet for a solution, but I don't seem to find it. I've even asked ChatGPT :), but it says my query is perfectly ok and should return my result sets.

Comment: *"but some actions affect a user, and some actions affect a media, but not always"* - It sounds like you might want a `LEFT JOIN` on these columns rather than `INNER`. If you have no log records that affect both a media and a user, then your query with two inner joins won't return anything. e.g. https://dbfiddle.uk/0O0U7lR2

Comment: Maybe I explained it a bit complicated, but every action is performed by a user. Some actions affect a user, and some actions affect a media, but there are also actions who affect both a user and a media. In that case, all three columns (user_id, affected_user_id, media_id) would have a value

Comment: And are there log records where all 3 values are populated AND the user_id is 1 for either of the two user columns? e.g. what does this return: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM logs WHERE media_id IS NOT NULL AND user_id IS NOT NULL AND affected_user_id IS NOT NULL AND (user_id = 1 OR affected_user_id = 1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, would this help?

```
SELECT log.action,
       log.action_time,
       log.user_id,
       users.name AS user_name,
       log.affected_user_id,
       log.media_id,
       media.title AS media_title,
       log.comment
  FROM log
       INNER JOIN users
          ON    (    users.id = log.user_id
                 AND log.user_id = 1)
             OR (    users.id = log.affected_user_id
                 AND log.affected_user_id = 1)
       INNER JOIN media ON media.id = log.media_id
```

---

**[EDIT]**, after you posted sample data:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM users;

        ID NAME
---------- -----
         1 Alex
         2 Heinz
         3 Frank

SQL> SELECT * FROM media;

        ID TITLE
---------- ---------------
         1 Harry Potter
         2 Some other book
         3 No idea

SQL> SELECT * FROM log;

        ID ACTION       ACTION_TIME            USER_ID AFFECTED_USER_ID   MEDIA_ID
---------- ------------ ------------------- ---------- ---------------- ----------
         1 MEDIA_EDIT   2023-08-23 17:56:04          1                           5
         2 USER_EDIT    2023-08-23 17:56:04          1                3
         3 MEDIA_BORROW 2023-08-23 17:56:04          1                3          1
```

Query, which joins `log` table to `users` table **twice**: once for `log.user_id` (inner join), another time for `log.affected_user_id` (outer join).

```
SQL> SELECT l.action,
  2         l.action_time,
  3         u.name AS user_name,
  4         au.name AS affected_user_name,
  5         m.title media_title
  6    FROM LOG  l
  7         JOIN users u ON u.id = l.user_id
  8         LEFT JOIN users au ON au.id = l.affected_user_id
  9         LEFT JOIN media m ON m.id = l.media_id;

ACTION       ACTION_TIME         USER_NAME AFFECTED_USER_NAME      MEDIA_TITLE
------------ ------------------- --------- ----------------------- ---------------
MEDIA_BORROW 2023-08-23 17:56:04 Alex      Frank                   Harry Potter
USER_EDIT    2023-08-23 17:56:04 Alex      Frank
MEDIA_EDIT   2023-08-23 17:56:04 Alex

SQL>
```

Comment: I tried it and it didn't seem to work. Just for me to understand, is the `(users.id = log.user_id AND log.user_id = 1)` a INNER JOIN and a WHERE at the same time?

Comment: You understood it correctly. If it doesn't work, consider posting some sample data and desired output (based on such data) - that might help us (the community) help you

Comment: For users, these results sets would be possible:
`(1, 'Alex')`
`(2, 'Heinz')`
`(3, 'Frank')`

For media, it would be these:
`(1, 'Harry Potter')`
`(2, 'Some other book')`
`(3, 'no idea')`

For log, there a a few possibilities:
`(1, 'MEDIA_EDIT', '2023-08-23 17:56:04', 1, Null, 5, Null)`
`(2, 'USER_EDIT', '2023-08-23 17:56:04', 1, 3, Null, Null)`
`(3, 'MEDIA_BORROW', '2023-08-23 17:56:04', 1, 3, 5, Null)`
The column comment is not really important, so I made it NULL

Comment: I edited answer; have a look, please.

Comment: I tried it a few times and it seems to work perfectly. I'm gonna learn about left join and outer join to fully understand you query, but thank you very much, you really helped me in a tricky situation!